MYSQL - Having An Issue Returning Column With Special Characters
I have a table named shops and  column named, shop_name and it has values such as



shop_name




Johnny and Co


Matt & Josh Sub


Lilly's Sub


Carpet Masters



I am try to return the rows that contain special characters.
I expect the following rows to be returned:
Matt & Josh Sub
Lilly's Sub

I am running the below queries:
Query 1:
First Query Returns No Results
select shop_name 
from shops 
where shop_name like '%[^0-9a-zA-Z]%';

Query 2
Second Query Returns All 4 Rows
select shop_name 
from shops 
where shop_name REGEXP '[^a-zA-Z0-9]';


Your queries should get a syntax error, since you're missing the comparison operator in the where clauses. I'm guessing you use REGEX or LIKE.

I don't see any difference between the two queries.

'%[^0-9a-zA-Z]%' is not a valid pattern for REGEX or LIKE. REGEX doesn't use % for wildcards, and LIKE doesn't support [...] character sets.

Use a regular expression to match a value that contains a non-alphanumeric character.
select shop_name 
from shops 
where shop_name REGEX '[^0-9a-zA-Z ]';

Notice that you also need to include space in the character set.
